# need help on grouping and row number

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm trying to create an ssrs report. Here's the data i have:

original data
[image: original data]

I need to grouping and numbering based on specific column but ignoring the Entire entry row, the final result should be like this.

result

[image: result]

What's the grouping should be on case like this so i can put the number just like in my screenshot ?

Answer (score 1):

Insert a matrix , row groups for Warehouse, Column1, Column 2 
and for column groups use Amount, insert amount field with aggregate function of sum.

to add in the No. row, you will need to insert a empty column between column1 and column2 and insert an expression similar to:

=RunningValue(Fields!Test_case.Value, CountDistinct,"Tablix3" )

Whereby Fields!Test_case.Value is equivelant to Column1 and Tablix3 is equivelant to your matrix.

Example of design and report outcome, just need to correct expression for the No. column:
[image]

Comment: There is no column grouping required here so a table would be needed, not a matrix.

Comment: Already tested but it doesn't work. It will multiple column with value from amount because it's matrix

Comment: as i said in my previous comment, don't use a matrix, just use a table

Comment: Yes, it works if we don't use a column group. Thanks!!